# Upgrade Operating System Snow Leopard to OS Sierra

Tags: snow-leopard, upgrade, adobe-photoshop

I know I must upgrade first to El Capitan before upgrading to OS Sierra.
But my question is will I loose installed Adobe Photoshop CS5 and my Bootcamp where I have 2 other costly programmmes installed.

Comment: Can you reinstall them after the upgrade?

Comment: Can't you go directly from SL to Sierra?

Comment: @fbara does CS5 run under Sierra? Bootcamp should be OK

Comment: I have no idea but I'm sure Adobe knows and it's probably on their site.

Answer (score -2):

Doubtful that you'll lose either Photoshop on the Mac partition or the Bootcamp partition itself while upgrading. Of course, backing up before moving forward is always the way to go.  :)